# How to use Response Data Handler Serialized into Data (Swift 3 via AlamoFire)

Tags: swift, alamofire

Any suggestions guys? I want to use func for calling API via Alamofire, but there's an error encountered 
Cannot convert value of type '(DataResponse)-> ()' to expected argument type '(DataResponse) -> Void'

Here's the code:

```
func authorize(emailAddress: String, password: String){

    let base_url = ApiRoute.userLogin.url

    let params: [String: Any]? = [
        "email": emailAddress,
        "password": password
    ]

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": CONTENT_TYPE,
        "devtoken": API_KEY,
        "userlang": USER_LANG
    ]

    Alamofire.request(base_url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { (response: DataResponse<ApiLoginResult>) in
            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                if let data = response.result.value{
                    print(response.result.value)
                }
                break
            case .failure(_):
                print(response.result.error)
                break
            }
    }
}
```

Can someone give me an idea how to implement this to my work

```
    // Response Data Handler - Serialized into Data
    func responseData(queue: DispatchQueue?, completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<Data>) -> Void) -> Self
```

Comment: post code here not screenshot.

Comment: So you have problem with Object mapping?

Comment: Yes, in object mapping, it's working if i use a simple alamofire with (response : DataResponse<APILoginResponse>) to (response) but I need to pass the data cause I'm using object mapping

Comment: Replace with this `responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in`

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: thanks bro, wait i'm going to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ObjectMapper you can map object like below. Hope you will got your idea.

```
Alamofire.request(base_url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                if let data = response.result.value{
                  print(response.result.value)

                   //Object mapping
                    let loginResult = Mapper<ApiLoginResult>().map(data)

                }
                break
            case .failure(_):
                print(response.result.error)
                break
            }
    }
```

Comment: let loginResult = Mapper<ApiLoginResult>().map(JSONObject: data)

Thanks bro

Answer (score 2):

`GetRequest` in `Alamofire` swift3 code

```
func getWebServicesFromAlamofireGetRequest() {

    self.myActivity.startAnimating()
    Alamofire.request("http:xxxx.com", method: .get, parameters: ["":""], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        self.myActivity.stopAnimating()
        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if response.result.value != nil {
                let jsonResponce = response.result.value as! NSDictionary

                print(jsonResponce)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error!)
            break

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
(response : DataResponse<APILoginResponse>)
```

be

```
(response)
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following Alamofire code

```
let strURL:String = "http://xxxx"
let parameters: Parameters = ["keyword": "current_timestamp"]

Alamofire.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
    print(response.data!)
                print(response.result)

                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }
}
```